# Template processing of arrays

Tags: gruntjs

Lets assume you have a configuration for paths in a `Gruntfile.js` and they can not be changed:

```
source: {
    directory: 'src',
    scripts: ['Classes/**/*.php', 'Tests/**/*.php']
}
```

What I need is to generate a value like `src/Classes/**/*.php,src/Tests/**/*.php` by using template processing.

But obviously when I do `<%= source.directory =>/<%= source.scripts =>` I get `src/Classes/**/*.php,Tests/**/*.php` which is not what I need.

So is there any elegant generic solution for this? **This means without changing the configuration, e.g. making `source.scripts` to a string like `{Classes,Tests}/**/*.php`**?

Comment: What value does dir need? I'm not understanding the goal.  It might be helpful to just write it out with strings and then work toward variable usage.

Comment: I've rewritten my question to  hopefully make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The Gruntfile is just javascript. You could move 'Classes' and 'Tests' to a separate array as such -

```
var phpDirs = ['Classes','Tests'],
phpFiles = '/**/*.php';

...

source: {
    directory: 'src',
    scripts: phpDirs.map(function(item){ return item + phpFiles })
}

....

"{" + phpDirs.join(",") + "}" + phpFiles; //maybe there's a better way to format this string
```

---

I'll leave it up to you to decide whether this makes your code better. for a simple case i'd probably do with some simple redundancy. for more complex cases i can see where it would be helpful.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it puts 'working logic' into the configuration, which should be only static, like a JSON or XML file. The reason for this requirement is maintainability just think of a server with more than 100 repositories with such build files.

Comment: Or in other words: This changes the configuration and this is what I don't want. See my question ;) ...

Comment: I disagree with the assertion that the Gruntfile should be static. There is complexity that can be reduced by working programmatically.

Comment: You get me totally wrong here! The assertion is that the configuration has to be static not the build file itself, both are physically separated in our organization. The primary problem with Grunt here is that whether or not you save the configuration paths relative or absolute in both cases you get problems with some tasks. And this is it what sucks with Grunt. I need a generic solution for this problem, so that I can use a common pattern how I store my paths non redundant and maintainable for every project. With build systems like Maven I never had those problems.

Comment: This is a good example what's wrong with many tasks in Grunt: https://github.com/SaschaGalley/grunt-phpcs/pull/34. But this is just one part of the problem. So my preferred solution here would be the possibility to prefix all items in an array through templates like `<%= prefix %>/<%= array %>`.